# Confusion in basic concept of pointers and strings

Tags: c

In my GCC 32-bit compiler, the following code gives the output

```
char *str1="United";
printf("%s",str1);
```

output:

```
United
```

then should I consider `char *str1="United";` the same as `char str1[]="United"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* str = "United";` is read-only. You wouldn't be able to reach inside the string and change parts of it:

```
*str = 'A';
```

Will most likely give you a segmentation fault.

On the other hand `char str1[] = "United";` is an array and so it can be modified as long as you don't exceed the space allocated for it (arrays cannot be resized). For example this is perfectly legal:

```
char str[] = "United";
str[0] = 'A';
printf("%s\n", str);
```

This will print `Anited`.

Comment: In `char *str = "United";`, the initialization copies a pointer value into the pointer object `str`. In `char str[] = "United";`, the initialization copies the 7-byte array value (`"United"` plus the terminating `'\0'`) into the *array* object `str`.

Comment: Yes, `char str[] = "United";` is equivalent to `char str[] = {'U', 'n', 'i', 't', 'e', 'd', '\0'};`. There is an implicit '\0' at the end. A proof of this is that `sizeof(str)` yields 7.

Answer (score 2):

The two are not the same: `char *str1="United"` gives you a pointer to a literal string, which must not be modified (else it's undefined behavior).  The type of a literal string should really be const but it's non-const for historical reasons.  On the other hand, `char str1[]="United"` gives you a modifiable local string.

Comment: "The type of a literal string should really be const char*" - what is the type of a string literal in C?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore technically a string literal is an anonymous `char[]`, which can only be pointed to (via `char *`). The `const`s are not part of the string literal's type, though (as stated) they incur UB if one attempts to change them.

Answer (score 1):

See the [comp.lang.c.faq, question 1.32](http://www.c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).  It basically boils down to the fact that declaring the string in array form (`char str[] = "foo"`) is identical to `char str[] = {'f','o','o'}`, which is identical to `char str[] = {102, 111, 111}`; that is, it is a normal array on the stack. But when you use a string literal in any other context it becomes "an unnamed, static array of characters, [which] may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified." (And trying to modify it results in undefined behavior wherever it happens to be stored, so don't).